# How can I re-iterate without limits in php

Tags: php

I have a function that retrieve the details of family member and can count the total of family member to the fifth generation. Below is my code snipped

```
function familyTree($id)
    {
        $total = 0;
        foreach(family($id) as $child){
            $total++;
            foreach(family($child->id) as $grand_child){
                $total++;
                foreach(family($grand_child->id) as $great_grand_child){
                    $total++;
                    foreach(family($great_grand_child->id) as $great_great_grand_child){
                    $total++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        return $total;
    }
```

My challenge is, how do I calculate the total number of family under the parent or anyone to infinity generation?

Comment: Read up on "recursion".

Comment: Can you point me to any resource on this? I know of recursion.. But cant wrap my head around this

Comment: Recursion. Basically you call `familyTree` *inside* `familyTree` itself.
Edit: This is probably one of the basic examples of recustions. If you don't see how to use recursion here, I don't believe you when you say you know it. :/ You might also look up "Depth-first search", that should help you.

Comment: That is the same question I have anyway. But there is no answer there

Comment: Something like this?
```php
<?php

function familyCountById($id)
{
 $family = family($id);
 $total = count($family);
 foreach($family as $familyMember){
  $total += familyCountById($familyMember->id);
 }

 return $total;
}

$fullCount = familyCountById($firstMember->id); // the offset member id, this one is not counted
```

Comment: @Giso. This worked like magic. Thanks

Comment: Tip: You can search the internet for things. *php recursive function* would have led you to tutorials as well if you want to know more.

Comment: It would have been good to have sample input and your exact desired output as part of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above comment by Giso Stallenberg, the correct answer should be the one below:

```
function familyTree($id)
{
    $family = family($id);

    $total = count($family);

    foreach(family($id) as $child){
        $total += familyTree($child->id);     
    }

    return $total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out :
assume the family function is defined and returns an array of all persons Childs, as we can get it from your question.
in any recursive functions, you need a STOP condition that is a leaf from family tree (persons with no child). if we get this condition we must return 1 that defined the individual leaf person. otherwise, we can iterate over his/her Childs and do it again for he/she. the only remained item is to plus plus the total variable for persons with children.

```
function familyTree($id) {
    $total = 0 ;
    if ( is_null ( family($id) ) {
       return 1 ;
    } 
    foreach (family($id) as $child) {
       $total += familyTree($child) ;
    }
    $total ++; 
    return $total ;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. I think this would throw multiple errors, as `family` is not defined as a function in your code, neither did you define the constant `id` you are accessing in the third line

Comment: you are right, I had some typing errors and have edited them but family function is based on the answer and assumed that is defined in the questioner code.

Comment: Then feel free to add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it